# Pandas Lookup to be deprecated - elegant and efficient alternative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lookup

The Pandas lookup function is to be deprecated in a future version. As suggested by the warning, it is recommended to use `.melt` and `.loc` as an alternative.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['X', 'X' , 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 
                         'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'],
                   'group': ["IT", "IT", "IT", "MV", "MV", "MV", 
                             "IT", "MV", "MV", "IT", "IT", "MV"]})

a = (pd.concat([df, df['B'].str.get_dummies()], axis=1)
     .groupby('group').rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()
     .sort_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True))        

df['count'] = a.lookup(df.index, df['B'])

>  Output Warning:  <ipython-input-16-e5b517460c82>:7: FutureWarning:
> The 'lookup' method is deprecated and will be  removed in a future
> version. You can use DataFrame.melt and DataFrame.loc as a substitute.
```

However, the alternative appears to be less elegant and slower:

```
b = pd.melt(a, value_vars=a.columns, var_name='B', ignore_index=False)
b.index.name='index'
df.index.name='index'
df = df.merge(b, on=['index','B'])
```

Is there a more elegant and more efficient approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, you can just use the index to assign new values.

```
dfn = df.set_index('B', append=True)
dfn['count'] = a.stack()
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)f for match by `index` and `B`:

```
df1 = df.rename_axis('i').join(a.stack().rename('count'), on=['i','B'])
print (df1)
    B group  count
i                 
0   X    IT    1.0
1   X    IT    2.0
2   Y    IT    1.0
3   X    MV    1.0
4   Y    MV    1.0
5   Y    MV    2.0
6   X    IT    2.0
7   X    MV    1.0
8   Y    MV    2.0
9   Y    IT    2.0
10  X    IT    2.0
11  Y    MV    2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use indexing lookup to replace the deprecated `lookup`:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df['B'])

df['count'] = a.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

Output:

```
    B group  count
0   X    IT    1.0
1   X    IT    2.0
2   Y    IT    1.0
3   X    MV    1.0
4   Y    MV    1.0
5   Y    MV    2.0
6   X    IT    2.0
7   X    MV    1.0
8   Y    MV    2.0
9   Y    IT    2.0
10  X    IT    2.0
11  Y    MV    2.0
```

Comment: This seems to make the assumption that we want all of the rows to be included in the lookup. What about if a specific selection of the rows are desired?

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions assume that you want to perform the lookup across all rows of the DataFrame, and your example does in fact do that. However, the original function allows for a list of row indices and a list of column names that form a set of pairs of coordinates to be looked up.

The following approach allows for this full functionality and seems to work in about the same time (slightly faster) as df.lookup:

```py
a.to_numpy()[a.index.get_indexer(df.index), a.columns.get_indexer(df['B'])]
```

Or to put it in code that better matches the old df.lookup API:

```py
df.to_numpy()[df.index.get_indexer(row_labels), df.columns.get_indexer(col_labels)]
```

I tested both the old lookup function and this new approach 100k times on a very small and a moderately large (100k x 4) DataFrame and in both cases this alternate approach ran marginally faster (39 seconds compared to 41.5 seconds)