# Python pandas 'lookup' is deprecated and will be removed. How to change the codes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

As you know, pandas dataframe.lookup method is deprecated and will be removed. (oh... hate this warning)

In my case, I've seen this warning,

> "FutureWaning: The 'lookup' method is deprecated and will be removed
> in a future version. You can use DataFrame.melt and DataFrame.loc as a
> substitute."

I've found out how to use melt and loc as a substitute for a simple example.

`df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ["A", "A", "B", "B"],'A': [80, 23, np.nan, 22],  'B': [80, 55, 76, 67]})`

```
0   A   80.0    80
1   A   23.0    55
2   B   NaN 76
3   B   22.0    67
```

lookup method:

`df.lookup(df.index, df['col'])`

```
array([80., 23., 76., 67.])
```

This is easy and intuitive,

but if  I change this using 'melt' and 'loc',

`df2 = df.melt('col')` 
`df2.loc[df2['col']==df2['variable']]['value'].values`

```
array([80., 23., 76., 67.])
```

Ok, I get the same result which I wanted to.

But if I have a big dataframe (row: 300,000 / column: 200), this "melt" function doesn't look good.

Is there any other way to substitute the pandas dataframe 'lookup' method?
Or can I make more efficient code than what I have done above?

Comment: It is not deprecated yet as it is future warning...so you can continue using it and If you wish an alternative then have a look on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65882258/pandas-lookup-to-be-deprecated-elegant-and-efficient-alternative

Answer (score 0):

Input data:

```
  col     A   B
0   A  80.0  80
1   A  23.0  55
2   B   NaN  76
3   B  22.0  67
4   A  10.0  15
```

```py
df1 = df.set_index("col").sort_index()
df1 = df1.stack().iloc[::len(df1.columns)]
```

Output result:

```py
>>> df1
col
A    A    80.0
     A    23.0
     A    10.0
B    B    76.0
     B    67.0
dtype: float64
```