# Pandas create column that shows absolute max value of the row, but keeps negatives

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
         a      b      c
124    -3.09  -0.38   2.34
2359    4.81   0.51  -1.53
56555  -4.34  -0.64   2.31
96786  -3.33  -3.34  -7.62
```

I want to calculate the absolute max value of each row in a new column **that keeps negatives as negatives.** The closest I've gotten is with the following:

```
df['new_column'] = df.abs().max(axis = 1)

new_column
3.09
4.81
4.34
7.62
```

But I need the new column to keep the negative signs—i.e. to look like this:

```
new_column
-3.09
 4.81
-4.34
-7.62
```

I've attempted a few things using abs().idxmax(), and am wondering if I need to find the location of the absolute max value, and then return the value in that location in the new column—just not sure how to do this. Thoughts?

Comment: Vectorized using `numpy` `df['new_column'] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), np.abs(df.to_numpy()).argmax(1)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using two steps: First, find the absolute max. Then see if absolute max equals any values in the DataFrame using `eq` and use the output as the power of `-1` to get the signs:

```
row_max = df.abs().max(axis=1)
df['new_column'] = row_max * (-1) ** df.ne(row_max, axis=0).all(axis=1)
```

Another option is to use `mask` to choose values:

```
df['columns'] = df.max(axis=1).mask(lambda x: x < row_max, -row_max)
```

Output:

```
          a     b     c  new_column
124   -3.09 -0.38  2.34       -3.09
2359   4.81  0.51 -1.53        4.81
56555 -4.34 -0.64  2.31       -4.34
96786 -3.33 -3.34 -7.62       -7.62
```

Comment: It's a shame `.lookup` has been deprecated as it was fairly useful. `df.lookup(df.index, df.abs().idxmax(axis=1))`. The new approach suggested in the documentation looks a little awkward... *sighs*

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, `lookup` was very useful. I thought of using the `factorize`+numpy indexing approach but it turned out that one is much, much slower (maybe I'm not using it too well) than the options I included here.

Comment: Ahh... couple of other suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65882258/pandas-lookup-to-be-deprecated-elegant-and-efficient-alternative

Comment: ... and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39171 is interesting

Answer (score 1):

I like the original idea you thought of, keeping with the theme:

```
# setup

data = {'a': [-3.09, 4.81, -4.34, -3.33],
        'b': [-.38, .51, -.64, -3.34],
        'c': [2.34, -1.53, 2.31, -7.62]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index= [124, 2359,56555,96786])
```

instead of:

```
df['new_column'] = df.abs().max(axis = 1)
```

let's change it to return the column instead of actual value:

```
max_col = df.abs().idxmax(axis = 1)
```

from there we can just iterate over it with enumerate for the row number and set it as the new column:

```
df['new_column'] = [df.loc[row,col] for row, col in zip(df.index, max_col)]
```

results:

```
          a     b     c  new_column
124   -3.09 -0.38  2.34       -3.09
2359   4.81  0.51 -1.53        4.81
56555 -4.34 -0.64  2.31       -4.34
96786 -3.33 -3.34 -7.62       -7.62
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this out as well—it seems be throwing a KeyError: 0

Comment: @carvalh3 Oops! I didn't see you had a custom index before. I just updated to fix it.

Comment: Works now—thanks!

Answer (score 0):

More than a year has passed, yet there is a faster solution to this problem.
From your dataset :

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
... ,a,b,c
... 124,-3.09,-0.38,2.34
... 2359,4.81,0.51,-1.53
... 56555,-4.34,-0.64,2.31
... 96786,-3.33,-3.34,-7.62
... """), sep=',',index_col=0)
>>> df
            a       b       c
124     -3.09   -0.38    2.34
2359     4.81    0.51   -1.53
56555   -4.34   -0.64    2.31
96786   -3.33   -3.34   -7.62
```

We can use [`argmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html) like so :

```py
v = df.values
df['new_column'] = v[range(len(v)), np.abs(v).argmax(axis=1)]
```

Output :

```
            a       b       c   new_column
124     -3.09   -0.38    2.34        -3.09
2359     4.81    0.51   -1.53         4.81
56555   -4.34   -0.64    2.31        -4.34
96786   -3.33   -3.34   -7.62        -7.62
```